# Is it possible to overlay a Geotiff in OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, geotiff-tiff, id-editor

I've got a GeoTiff I'd like to overlay into OSM while editing in iD editor so I can extract features, but I don't see an option anywhere. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

iD is an editor for starters, they typically do not need this type of functionality. You can do this with JOSM and the PicLayer plugin though.